# How to select column name in Firebird trigger after insert

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I am using the Firebird trigger. I want to fetch party_name on the base of party_id after insert trigger. And insert party_name into the logs table. Here is my code.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER cash_after_insert CASH_FLOW 
AFTER INSERT 
POSITION 0 
AS
DECLARE getPartyName for
(select party_name from party where party_id=NEW.party_id);
BEGIN
insert into logs(date,username,logs)values('now',getPartyName,'added data');
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring [a cursor](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-declare-cursor), which requires additional statements ([`OPEN`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-open), [`FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-fetch), and [`CLOSE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-close)) to actually retrieve values. Instead, you can use a select expression which is a lot simpler than using an explicit cursor:

```sql
insert into logs(date,username,logs) values (
  'now', 
  (select party_name from party where party_id = NEW.party_id), 
  'added data');
```

As an aside, the syntax you use in your question is incorrect (or at least incomplete). For example, the create trigger statement should be `CREATE TRIGGER cash_after_insert for CASH_FLOW`, the cursor declaration misses the `CURSOR` keyword (`DECLARE getPartyName cursor for ...`), and `date` is a reserved word, so needs to be quoted (`"DATE"`).

In other words, use:

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER cash_after_insert for CASH_FLOW 
AFTER INSERT 
POSITION 0 
AS
BEGIN
insert into logs ("DATE", username, logs) values (
  'now', 
  (select party_name from party where party_id = NEW.party_id),
  'added data');
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```